# Dilogarithm of -1/2?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polylogarithms

$\mathrm{Li}_2(\frac12)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}$ (L. Euler, 1768)

$\mathrm{Li}_2(-\frac12)=-\pi\arg\left(\frac{H(-1-\frac{\log(2)}{\pi i})}{H(\frac{\log(2)}{\pi i})}\right)$,
where $H(z)$ is the hyperfactorial.

Q: Can the dilogarithm of -1/2 be represented by values of the elementary functions?

Comment: I doubt it. Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html to see what's known about the dilogarithm.

Comment: Thanks@Gerry Myerson : For about 250 yr, unfortunately, we had no identities, to be represented as elementary functions, for the dilogarithm of -1/2(or 1/9).

Comment: @SangkyuKim You can have this representation: $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac12\right)=-\frac12\ln^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac13\right)$. There is certainly no _known_ representation of $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac13\right)$ in terms of elementary functions, despite that this area is well-studied now. I doubt very much there exists an unknown representation (but I almost certain it hasn't yet been proved it doesn't exist).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov : \begin{align}\mathrm{Li}_2(-\frac12)=2\pi\arg(H(\frac{\log(2)}{\pi i}))+\log(2)\log(\frac{\log(2)}{\pi})\end{align}I discovered the above identity. I want to find the argument of the above hyperfactorial to be represented by elementary functions. Maybe I guess we cannot get it...

Comment: Hyperfactorial https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html